# What would you call this "RAID" ? RAID 1+6?

Tags: raid, raid1, snapshot, raid6

I have Snapraid running as snapshot RAID6 (2-parity disks) for my 9 disk array which calculates new parity once a day. Then I have Drivepool duplicating certain very important folders on the array to all the data disks in realtime as in RAID1.

Would this still be considered as RAID1+6 even though it's kinda hybrid realtime/snapshot array or is there a different name for it?

Answer (score 2):

As Chopper mentions: No.

Your drive pool is duplicating the data across the same physical disks in the same RAID6 array. Meaning, you lose more than the two drives, and you will still lose all your data despite the drivepool mirroring.

To do something similar RAID 6+1, you would have to create two RAID6 arrays on the Snapraid and make sure the logical drives you present to your drive pool reside on separate RAID6 arrays and then have the drive pool mirror the data between the two physical RAID6 arrays.

Note: I said similar to RAID6+1 because even that wouldn't be considered really RAID 6+1

edit: So - Did a little more digging on snapRAID. It's not RAID6 at all - so, it can't be considered RAID6+1 because there is no RAID6 component to it. You have individual drives with software double parity to account for double drive failures.

It would still be no because there is no RAID6 to being with.

Comment: But why would I lose all the data in +2 drive failure when Snapraid is functioning like JBOD with 2-parity redundancy?. Every physical data disk is also a logical drive and Drivepool just pools them on a virtual drive and mirrors the important data to every disk. I can take the whole array down and plug them in one by one and all the data is intact.

Comment: Data or Parity is never striped across the drives like in real RAID5/6.

Comment: Answer edited/updated.

Comment: Ty for answering, So I guess this could be called bastardized real-time mirroring with snapshot 2-parity redundancy. I still think its way more safer than standard raids and I can decide which data is truly important and needs to be mirrored immediately across the disks.

Answer (score 0):

> Would this still be considered as RAID1+6

No.